# Unable to set proxy in SonarQube running in OpenShift(OKD)

Tags: sonarqube, openshift, okd

I'm running the [sonarqube-openshift-docker](https://github.com/OpenShiftDemos/sonarqube-openshift-docker) build of sonarqube.  I need to set the proxy Sonar uses so it can get to the Marketplace and pull down a Java profile.

I've tried setting a deployment a config env name/value pair:
JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS = "-Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort="

I've also tried setting HTTP_PROXY_HOST, HTTP_PROXY_PORT, HTTPS_PROXY_HOST,  HTTPS_PROXY_PORT name/value pairs.

All of these make it through to the environment on the container side, but Sonar isn't using those.

Changing the sonar.properties file in the container doesn't work since it's not persistent and gets stomped on with a restart.

I also tried adding it here, but that didn't work.

```
template:
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/container.sonarqube.image.entrypoint: '["./bin/run.sh -Dhttp.proxyHost=<myProxy:port>"]'
```

I am guessing I need to pass it in somewhere in the YAML file, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to provide **host** and **port** in separate properties:

```
http.proxyHost=
http.proxyPort=
```

Take a look at the sonar.properties file [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/8123665684c3ea60147c3288e60378ecae65aacc/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties#L295).

Comment: Setting it in that properties file does not persist through container restarts.  So I need to figure out how to pass it in at container startup.

Comment: you are right, but you can pass every property from the configuration file as a system property like you tried with `proxyHost`. Providing port and host like `-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxx` should work. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Running SonarQube on OpenShift, I use a template that ubstalls a ConfigMap setting HTTP proxies configuration.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-template
objects:
[...]
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-conf
  data:
    sonar.properties: |-
      http.nonProxyHosts=${PROXY_EXCLUDE}
      http.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
      http.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
      https.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST}
      https.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT}
    wrapper.conf: |-
      wrapper.java.command=java
      wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dsonar.wrapped=true
      wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.awt.headless=true
[...]
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
[...]
         volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/conf
            name: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-conf
[....]
    volumes:
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 420
        name: ${APPLICATION_NAME}-conf
[...]
parameters:
- name: APPLICATION_NAME
  value: sonarqube
- name: PROXY_HOST
  value: proxy.example.com
- name: PROXY_PORT
  value: "3128"
- name: PROXY_EXCLUDE
  value: "*.internal.domain.example.com"
```